# MySQL join not using index when adding a dependent join

Tags: mysql, left-join, query-optimization

When I perform EXPLAIN on the following query to fetch users with bookings

```
SELECT user.id
FROM user
    LEFT JOIN booking
        ON booking.user_id = user.id
            AND booking.end_timestamp > 1706878800
            AND booking.end_timestamp <= 1706882400
            AND booking.status IN ('pending', 'progress', 'done');
```

I get the following result:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | user | NULL | index | NULL | status | 1 | NULL | 17644 | 100 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | booking | NULL | ref | status,user_id_start_timestamp,user_id_status_end_timestamp,end_timestamp | user_id_status_end_timestamp | 5 | db.user.id | 403 | 0.01 | Using where; Using index |

As you can see, it automatically uses the index `user_id_status_end_timestamp` for the `booking` table.

But when I add another join to the query to include `address` which depends on the `booking` table:

```
SELECT user.id
FROM user
    LEFT JOIN booking
        ON booking.user_id = user.id
            AND booking.end_timestamp > 1706878800
            AND booking.end_timestamp <= 1706882400
            AND booking.status IN ('pending', 'progress', 'done')
    LEFT JOIN address ON booking.address_id = address.id;
```

now it no longer uses any index for the `booking` table making the query very slow even though it shows the same list of possible keys:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | user | NULL | index | NULL | status | 1 | NULL | 17644 | 100 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | booking | NULL | ALL | status,user_id_start_timestamp,user_id_status_end_timestamp,end_timestamp | NULL | NULL | NULL | 9509525 | 100 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x98040) |
| 1 | SIMPLE | address | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | db.booking.address_id | 1 | 100 | Using index |

Of course, if I add `USE INDEX (user_id_status_end_timestamp)`, it works, but why is MySQL not using the index automatically in this case?

I am using MySQL version 5.7.42.

**EDIT**

Please note that I need both the joins to be left join. The original query is much bigger. I have trimmed it down to focus only on the part where the problem lies for easier understanding and debugging. To explain why they both need to be left joins, here is what one of the where clauses look like:

```
(booking.id IS NULL OR address.country_id = :countryId)
```

Comment: How slow is _"very slow"_? When you add the address table MySQL needs booking.address_id, which is not included in that index. Because the index is no longer covering, and two of the predicates are ranges, MySQL has decided that no single index is suitable. The `index map: 0x98040` (b10011000000001000000) suggests you have 20 indices on the booking table. Is that correct? What is your full query? The example query included makes little sense, as you are left joining two tables but not returning any of their values. Please add the DDL for the two tables to your question.

Comment: "How slow" is not relevant here because as you can see in the table there's millions of rows so any form on query on the table without index is out of the question. "When you add the address table MySQL needs booking.address_id" you are absolutely right about this part, I had just created a new index that covered all the columns in the join plus the address_id column (user_id, end_timestamp, status, address_id) and that solved the problem. Although, to me this is highly non-intuitive because address table is a separate join with its own foreign key so I have no idea why this solution works.

Comment: Also, at this point I am not really sure if practically in the application which is a better solution: USE INDEX (user_id_status_end_timestamp) OR creating this new index that includes address_id.

Comment: It works because the index is now covering, meaning there is no additional read from the clustered index required. Also, in switching the order of `end_timestamp` and `status` the initial range scan is more selective. Although not covering, an index on just `(user_id, end_timestamp)` _may_ perform OK.

Comment: For users _with_ bookings, get rid of `LEFT`.

Comment: @user1191247 an index on just `(user_id, end_timestamp)` performs absolutely fine but unfortunately MySQL doesn't automatically use it in all cases. Depending on the values passed to `booking.end_timestamp` in the join condition, sometimes the index is used and in other cases not. It could be due to the kind of data stored in the table.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. [When is "EDIT"/"UPDATE" appropriate in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127639/266284) Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Again: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Comments are for asking for clarifications to be edited into posts & for giving problems with posts. Confusion will not be causeed because after posts are edited comments should be deleted & flagged for deletion. Again: Inserting "EDIT"s is inappropriate. I'm done.

Comment: @user1191247 Please feel free to add your first suggestion regarding covering index as an answer because that actually solved my problem. I did a thorough testing with different parameters and it worked in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first query:

```sql
SELECT user.id
FROM user
    LEFT JOIN booking
        ON booking.user_id = user.id
            AND booking.end_timestamp > 1706878800
            AND booking.end_timestamp <= 1706882400
            AND booking.status IN ('pending', 'progress', 'done');
```

the index `user_id_status_end_timestamp (user_id, status, end_timestamp)` is covering, meaning there is no additional read from the clustered index required. When you add the join to the `address` table, the `booking.address_id` is now required but not available in the index. This now requires an additional read from the clustered index (table data), so MySQL decides the index is not suitable for the whole join (it may still be used for per row range scans).

If you add `address_id` to the index, it becomes covering again and should be chosen by the optimizer. Switching the order of `status` and `end_timestamp` may also improve performance.

```sql
ALTER TABLE booking
    ADD INDEX idx_user_endtime_stat_address (user_id, end_timestamp, status, address_id);
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `LEFTs`, they seem to be "wrong" for your application.

`bookings` needs

```
INDEX(end_timestamp, status),
INDEX(status, end_timestamp)
```

Since you are filtering on dates and status, that should be the first table to work with, but `LEFT` prevents that.  Instead, you get all users, together will NULLs from the other tables.

The Optimizer will pick between those indexes based on table statistics and the values provided.